# мне нужно чтобы при нажатии на кнопку страница сайта прокручивалась до определенного div вот что я сделал (это не работает где ошибка)

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, thymeleaf

```
 <div class="col-lg-4">
        <h2>Характеристики </h2>
        <p><a   href="/Iphone6/characteristics" onclick="slowScroll('#characteristics')" 
 role="button"><h4>Більше »</h4></a></p>
    </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->

 <div id="characteristics" class="row featurette mt-5">
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <h2 class="featurette-heading">Характеристики </h2>
        <p class="lead">Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Vestibulum id ligula porta 
  felis euismod semper. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur. Fusce 
  dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5 order-md-1">
        <img th:src="@{/images/big5.jpg}" class="rounded float-right"  style="width:90%" />
    </div>
   </div>
```

js

```
   function slowScroll(id){
   var offset=0    /*пропускає шапку*/
    $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(id).offset ().top - offset
    },500);
  return false;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это можно сделать посредством обычного якоря в HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Быстрый переход внутри документа</title>
</head>
<body>
<p><a href="#first">Первый блок</a></p>
<p><a href="#second">Второй блок</a></p>
<div id="first" style="height: 100vh; background: #bbb">
    Первый блок с большой высотой
</div>
<div id="second" style="height: 1000px; background: #ff0">
    Второй блок с большой высотой
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: вы где html4 взяли ? с 2000 ?

Comment: как сделать отступ сверху на 5px при переходе (есть отступление в самом блоке но оно его игнорирует и переходть прямо к тексту)

Comment: @MaximLensky спасибо, поправил

Comment: @MaxBahnuik отметьте пожалуйста мой вариант как правильное решение. По поводу отступов: почитайте про padding и margin

Comment: простите некорректно поставил вопрос
моя проблема заключается в том thimlife не подключает css (не выполняет код из отдельного файла css) в отдельном файле я указал отступления но не выполняются